# How to pass some data to Django views.py?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want send product id to my views.

Templates

```html
<div class="products__header--search-result">
    <ul>
        {% for product in products %}
            <li onclick="change('{{ product.id }}')"><a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    function change(foo) {
        $.ajax({
            url: {% url 'dashboard' %},
            data: {
                'foo': foo,
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

views.py

```py
myRequets = request.GET.get('foo')
```

But myRequets return 'None'

How can I fix this?
Is there a better way to pass values to views.py?

Comment: Do you want to post some data with AJAX in Django or pass parameters to views ?

Comment: @Rvector I want when i click on any of li send product id to view.

Comment: You can do it without AJAX, do you really need it?

Comment: @DiegoMagalhães No i just find this solution in my search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JS to do this because Django allows parameters in urls:

```
# URLconf
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('product/', views.product),
    path('product/<int:product_id>/', views.product),
]
```

views.py

```
# View (in product/views.py)
def product(request, product_id=None):
    products = None
    if product_id:
       # Output the appropriate page of product entry, according to product_id.
        return ...
    # Output the appropriate page when product_id is None
    return ...
```

Source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#example (adapted)

Then in your template:

```
{% if products %}
<div class="products__header--search-result">
    <ul>
        {% for product in products %}
            <li><a href="/product/{{ product_id }}/">{{ product.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```